# Get Input value by button in vue

Tags: php, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I have a form like:

```
<form action="{{route('articles.create')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="typeId" :value="articleTypeSelected"/>
    @foreach($types as $type)
      <button  type="submit" v-model="articleTypeSelected" :value="{{ $type->id }}"
      class="dropdown-item text-left">{{ $type->name }}
      </button>
   @endforeach
</form>


  <script>
       window.app = new Vue({
           el: '#app',
           data: {
               articleTypeSelected: []
           }
       });
    </script>
```

I'm trying to get the input value on button clicked for submitting a form using Vuejs2 but always get an empty result like the data.

Comment: Where are you trying to get the input value?

Comment: When the button clicked!

Comment: What does your Vue instance look like?

Comment: Post your vuejs codes here

Comment: You have issue in your form constructions.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
@foreach($types as $type)

  <a href="{{ route('articles.create') }}" class="dropdown-item"
      onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('type{{$type->id}}').submit();">

  {{ $type->name }}

    <form id="type{{$type->id}}" action="{{ route('articles.create') }}" method="post">
       @csrf
       <input type="hidden" name="typeId" value="{{$type->id}}"/>

    </form> 

  </a>

@endforeach
```